# Google lookup function simply uses the last value no matter what

Tags: google-sheets, lookup

I have 3 columns of interest.
Column A is a list of numbers written out as strings. (seven, eleven, nineteen)
Column B is a list of numbers as numbers. (7, 11,19)
Cell C1 has the formula: =LOOKUP("seven",A1:A3,B1:B3)
this formula always returns 19 if there is ANYTHING in A3
If there is nothing in A3, it returns 11, and only if there is nothing in A2, A3 will it return 7.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fJZt.png)
What am I misunderstanding?
Thanks

I was expecting the test to find the matching string and yield the number in the range but it always skips to the last value by default.

If I put a string in A3 of "cow" it yields 19
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxebw.png)
if I put a string in A3 of "three" it yields 11
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZAvV.png)

I've also tried VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP with worse results.
I tried with and without "$" in ranges.

What kind of logic is this? lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As per [LOOKUP()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256570) documentation:*

```js
LOOKUP(search_key, search_range|search_result_array, [result_range])
```

- *The LOOKUP function **will only work** properly `if data in search_range or search_result_array is sorted`. Use VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, or other
  related functions if data is not sorted.*

*You may try this for your test dataset:*

```js
=xlookup("seven",A:A,B:B,)
```

Comment: Yeah, Thanks. I don't really understand what that means. "if the data is sorted". I mean - I know how to sort data. What I don't follow is what is the lookup doing that is breaking because the data isn't in some seemingly arbitrary order? That part confuses me. Like "which order would be the correct one for this lookup to work? Alphabetically? Numerically, high to low? Low to high? :)   
Seems that a lookup should still do it's LOOKING UP regardless of what order the dataset is in.  I'm not asking for the FIRST instance of the result. There would be only one, so it's not making sense yet.

Comment: Secondly, which may be just for me, it doesn't seem possible to sort a column of data that is included in a lookup if that column changes every time someone fills a form. Is there a formula trick like "as if sorted according to x, y, z rules" I could add to my formula so that it's sorting the data virtually or something prior to looking? I did mention I tried V and H lookups with worse results. I never heard of XLOOKUP before and is 17th down the page in a search for "LOOKUP" so I'd probably never have found it. Thanks for the tip. That seems to work for my example. No sorting needed. :)